# How to remove Required field from an entity in Jhipster

Tags: jhipster

I am new to Jhipster and I want to remove required field from column without changing anything else like
table name in h2 db or the names of the columns in that table. I tried to remove @NotNull annotation from entity name and set field in database to null but when i run integration test using
**mvnw verify** i get this error

```
EmployeeResourceIT.checkCompanyIsRequired:124 Status expected:<400> but was:<201>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must modify the `EmployeeResourceIT` test also so that it does not verify company requirement anymore.

It would be simpler to modify your JDL file to change the constraint on this field and import it.
And if you did not use JDL, you should learn it, it's more powerful than answering questions (see https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/getting-started)

You can create your JDL file from your existing project using `jhipster export-jdl`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! actually I used JDL file to generate my entities first time, but I made some changes in some entities (tables name, columns name..) so I guess if I removed **required** in jdl file would overwrite all my changes..

Comment: That's correct but you could do it in a git branch and then merge back in your main branch to keep your changes. But if you don't want to do so, you can continue what you started by fixing errors one by one, starting by the failing test.

Comment: I solved this by removing `@Notnull` and  `nullable = false` from Entity_name.java and I removed `"fieldValidateRules": ["required"]` from .jhipster/<entity_name>.json and I run this command `jhipster entity <entity_name> --skip-client --skip-db-changelog` then I chose the first option to regenerate the existing entity and Finally I  fixed the errors one by one (tables and column names in my case ) ..Thank you again @Gaël Marziou for your help!